# ubuntu postfix send mail marked as spam

Tags: spam

I set up a mail server, when I give Gmail to send test message is marked as spam

system: ubuntu + postfix + dkim + dk + spf + ptr

This is the message header

```
Delivered-To: test@gmail.com
Received: by 10.229.145.65 with SMTP id c1csp254265qcv;
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 21:45:43 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.70.33.102 with SMTP id q6mr27519891pdi.39.1405485942641;
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 21:45:42 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <root@myservice.com>
Received: from myservice.com (myservice.com. [192.157.254.126])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id gx11si9099827pbd.62.2014.07.15.21.45.41
        for <test@gmail.com>;
        Tue, 15 Jul 2014 21:45:42 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of root@myservice.com designates 192.157.254.126 as permitted sender) client-ip=192.157.254.126;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@myservice.com designates 192.157.254.126 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=root@myservice.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@myservice.com
Received: from myservice.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by myservice.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 45F265A2061F
    for <test@gmail.com>; Wed, 16 Jul 2014 00:45:40 -0400 (EDT)
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; s=mail; d=myservice.com; c=simple; q=dns;
    b=iT7uvHDnQlxwHLtoPLuM7MA4IvWuzWCtWXALDWuSpDOQnMnMjFCfPwzYF3dOPyPGn
    1fMqWylOiHoimUT+EAOwLFxdW0/xvcmF319dhAj6KNsA+Dx61an1f4S54xKrxKbN0h6
    D6XXNPTcMbBoMOnzayzCUoIgpMoNZLh5w9+osXs=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=simple/simple; d=myservice.com; s=mail;
    t=1405485940; bh=zm1Rb6iYct2ei4UtHDsR95MNcq4=;
    h=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:Message-ID:List-Unsubscribe:
     MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
    b=hD/6T0LxzUi8CtW0JccGfeByyN+jgLYoJ2Dz40+6abi+/F749mHwL9MtIn/Ax4SjA
     KNZK8od0qRO9RR5tRv4vYh53oAKqVDJyc79Uv/wGwI/4rBYMI20oASE5Gw15icB7j2
     fjZ9IM3COYVLnIOvzV7D1PAAHdUtEGp/g0ZKOjYI=
Date: Wed, 16 Jul 2014 12:45:40 +0800
To: h271299921 <test@gmail.com>
From: root <root@myservice.com>
Reply-To: no-reply@myservice.com
Subject: this is my email
Message-ID: <5ec8f7d42180e6aa8874388570847249@myservice.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-YarnBlaster: bulk
List-Unsubscribe: <https://www.myservice.com/?mail=mailinglist/unsubscribe_token/1405485940ZHoxUEtySG9acG9VK3c4aWNlR3R6WTl5R2txamR4SUxVK0lYR2E5VFNHVT0uLjE0MDUzNTczODA=>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative
boundary="b1_5ec8f7d42180e6aa8874388570847249"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

[this](http://www.mail-tester.com/web-gi2vA8) is my test result using mail-tester.com.

Comment: Not enough information. Config files are needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are is listed in list.dnswl.org. Also your email dont have (properly identified) text body parts.

You can check your email reputation score on the below link.
Also you will get suggestions to improve your email so that it will get in inbox instead of SPAM.

http://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: this is test result http://www.mail-tester.com/web-gi2vA8

Comment: this is message content: <p>To get an email\'s HTML source using Outlook for example, right click inside the message and click "View Source" then cut and paste the resulting HTML in the the HTML text box below.</p>

Answer (score 0):

[Other people on your ISP are spamming](http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/query/SBL228558).   The only things you can do about that are talk to your hosting provider about their reputation and either find a different one or use a mail relay provider such as Mandrill or Sendgrid.

I would recommend talking to them first and then voting with your wallet, even if you decide to use a mail relay provider.  Let them know that tolerating spammers will lose them customers.

[Judging by the anti-spam talk](http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/listings/enzu.com) [about this hosting provider](https://cleantalk.org/blacklists/AS18978), [ENZU just love hosting spam](http://www.daddysnuts.com/enzu). Ditch them and let them know why. It will be *years* before their reputation improves, even after they start trying to clean up their act.